# Drawable Button or Clickable ImageView in android

Tags: android, performance, button, imageview

just wanted to make a clickable image and I don't know which option will be more efficient. 
What's better: a button that has a background image or a imageview that is clickable?

Comment: Use `ImageButton` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: write setonclick listeners for imageview

Comment: Or a TextView that is clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `clickListener` to `ImageView` is a cleaner way. In the button, you may face issues like, image not being bordered properly. It can be done with changes in xml, but its an overhead.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.<ImageViewId>);
imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the `onClick(View view)` method, handle the click event.